# In Chart js how to get date selector

Tags: charts

How to get date picker in chart.js chart to get historical data with in the selected range of date from the client side.

If I give a query in the backend it gives a chart but if I give from client side i.e. from front end it doesn't send the chart. It replies with the JSON data for selected dates

Comment: Tnks for the correction @swati

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js has no plugin for a datetimepicker. I recommend you the eonasdan [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). For an interval two pickers are needed. After a succesful implementation of these you need a **form** for the userinputs (client side) to $_POST or $_GET inputs to your server side. You need to refer the used librarys in the header of your HTML-Doc.

**HTML**

(optional you can add some bootstrap-glyphicons):

```
<form id="dates" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='startinterval'>
      <input id="start" type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='endinterval'>
      <input id="end" type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**
create a new JS-file and use jQuery and EONASDAN

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#startinerval').datetimepicker({
          //specify your datetimepicker
    });
    $('#endinterval').datetimepicker({
          //specify your datetimepicker
    });  
});
```

I guess you query a database to get the chartdata. So you need to query your database in dependence to the userinputs of the datepickers. Afterwards, store the resulting data in an array and convert them to a JSON:

```
$data = array('xaxis' => $xaxis, 'yaxis' => $yaxis);
json_encode($data);
```

Keep in mind that this code is only an example and needed to embed in your own code!!!

Do you use Ajax for server/client communication?

Comment: yes, i am using ajax and not in php i am using node js @N3wbie

Comment: Okay, this makes not a big different on the client side. You need to implement a datetimepicker and transfer userinputs to you server, then query the database! The resulting values of the query should be x-y-axis of your chart. Your questions is not really concrete, I don't know where your problem is.

Comment: ok i will explain in detail if i give value for start and end date in query correctly it fetches the graph. But if i entered value from frontend it just reply  the JSON data..@N3wbie

Comment: Graphs of Chart.js need data in JSON-Format. I guess you want to develope a website, am I right? Edit your document-ready function with a console.log, which shows the transferred data: `console.log(chartdata);`. If you would edit the question with your code, I could better help you!